# No redirect when using IdentityServer3 and angular

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I am currently developing an authorization system prototype using ASP.NET Web API 2 and angular. For the authorization and authentication I'm using IdentityServer3.

The architecture looks like this:

- Frontend: Angular (6)
- Client: ASP.NET Web API 2
- Authorization Server: ASP.NET Web API 2
- Resource Server: ASP.NET Web API 2

The angular app is served by the client and *only* makes API calls to the client.
I want to use the hybrid flow. So the client communicates with the resource server.

When making an API call by typing in the URL into the adress bar like this:

```
http://localhost:12059/api/v1/orders
```

everything is working perfectly fine. The browser redirects the user to the IdentityServer where he can authenticate and authorize.

But when I'm making the *same* API call to the client using angular the user is not being redirected. he simply gets an error in the console:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

The angular api call looks like this:

```
getOrders(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`/api/v1/orders`);
}
```

And the endpoint in C# like this:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    var token = user.FindFirst("access_token").Value;
    var result = await CallApi(token);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

It doesn't make much sense to me since the client makes the authorization request.